# How to remove title tag from jasper at run time?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My title tag has 3 child one image and 2 text-fields. In any case if all the 3 child are null i want to delete/hide the complete title tag from report.Is there a way to do it at run time without changing my jrxml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your jrxml into a `JasperDesign` object and set the title `null`

example

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("jasper/dbTest2.jrxml");
design.setTitle(null);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
```

Note to use this you need to know **before you fill** the report if the band is to remove or not.

After you filled the report you will have a `JasperPrint` this can also be manipulate but you need to do it page by page (no more title band, but page representation). Removing object means you need to move all others...

The **correct way** normally is to use the `printWhenExpression` on the `title` band

```
<title>
    <band height="201">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{image1}!=null && $F{text1}!=null && $F{text2}!=null]]></printWhenExpression>
        ... your images and text fields
    </band>
</title>
```

So consider to modify your jrxml or to add this expression on runtime.

```
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load("jasper/dbTest2.jrxml");
JRDesignBand title = (JRDesignBand) design.getTitle();
title.setPrintWhenExpression(new JRDesignExpression("$F{image1}!=null && $F{text1}!=null && $F{text2}!=null"));
```